# How can we replace exchange with exchange copy?

Tags: apache-camel

Is there a way to replace an exchange with a copy? I get a copy of an exchange in a process and I need replace/overwrite existing exchange with a copy. Scenario is that a SOAP request is getting stored in exchange body and body type is a custom object. Now when request goes to the server, response gets stored in exchange body and body type changes to input stream. If response is not what I need, then I need to replace exchange with the exchange copy and resend the request.

Excerpt from process(...)

```
Exchange copy = null;
copy = ExchangeHelper.createCopy(exchange, true);
```

There is setBody, but nothing like setExchange or replaceExchangeWithCopy.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your case in Camel there are 2 type of body i.e.

```
exchange.getIn.setBody

exchange.getOut.setBody
```

That mean you can store your request in **IN body** and the response in **OUT body**, so after checking your response which is in OUT body is correct or not you can again use your IN body content.

Make sure your `Exchange pattern` is **INOUT**.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that  using '<setExchangePattern pattern="InOut"/>' however response is getting stored in getIn and body type changes to InputStream.

Comment: If the response is storing in IN body and you don't know the reason why it is happening then to fix your issue you can set your request to OUT body. It will work.